# issues with .wav file in SFML

Tags: visual-studio, sfml

Hey everybody i recently started c++ on a tutorial from a couple of years ago. I am having an issue using SFML for a .wav file in the main program(this is a simplified one having the same issue). The file is in the same folder as project and that is where the directory looks and the name is spelled the same and everything. I am using the most recent SFML and visual studio 2017. Forgive me if the upload looks weird it is my first time posting here.

```html
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>


using namespace sf;

int main()
{
 VideoMode vm(1920,1080);
 RenderWindow window(vm, "SpriteTest", Style::Fullscreen);

 //****ERROR SHOWS HERE****
 sf::SoundBuffer chop;
 if (!chop.loadFromFile("audio/chop.wav"))
 {
  std::cout << "ERROR LOADING AUDIO" << std::endl;
 }
 sf::Sound chopNoise;
 chopNoise.setBuffer(chop);

 //****THIS IS THE ERROR

 /*Exception thrown at 0x6A36E344 (vcruntime140.dll) in sprite tester.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x005C5000.

  my .wav file is in the audio file in the project file which is where the working directory is
 */


 // shield test
 Texture shield;
 shield.loadFromFile("graphics/shield.png");
 Sprite shieldSprite;
 shieldSprite.setTexture(shield);
 shieldSprite.setPosition(1500, 800);
 //background test
 Texture backgroundTexture;
 backgroundTexture.loadFromFile("graphics/background2.png");
 Sprite background;
 background.setTexture(backgroundTexture);
 background.setPosition(0, 0);
 //lazer test
 Texture lazerTexture;
 lazerTexture.loadFromFile("graphics/lazer2.png");
 Sprite lazerSprite;
 lazerSprite.setTexture(lazerTexture);
 lazerSprite.setPosition(200, 500);

 while (window.isOpen())
 {
  if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
   window.close();
  if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))
  {
   
  }
  window.clear();
  window.draw(background);
  window.draw(shieldSprite);
  window.draw(lazerSprite);
  window.display();
 }
}
```

OUTPUT FILE::S

'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\Debug\sprite tester.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-graphics-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-window-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-window-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-window-d-2.dll'
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-system-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-audio-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-system-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-system-d-2.dll'
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\sfml-system-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kyle9\Desktop\Game dev book stuff\Visual Studios stuff\sprite tester\sprite tester\openal32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fltLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_b9b9c39e4e2b88eb\ig9icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_b9b9c39e4e2b88eb\igc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput8.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\hid.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\InputHost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MMDevAPI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AudioSes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'sprite tester.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x640DE340 (vcruntime140.dll) in sprite tester.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00B00000.

Comment: Does the line `ERROR LOADING AUDIO` appear in your console?

Comment: yes. it does and then a bunch of weird symbols

Comment: then the problem is, that `audio/chop.wav` can not be read. Assuming the wav is valid: Make sure the program finds the file and the path is correct.

Comment: I've tried that. I even put the full path in at one point and still the same issue. Is there a certain size it needs to be?

Comment: Not really. I would try 2 other things: 1. Does C++ really find that file? Try to open it with `std::ifstream in("audio/chop.wav");` for example and do `std::cout << in.good() << std::endl` Does it print 1 or 0 ? 0 would mean, that it can't find the file. 2. Try a different wav file.

Comment: So I ran the in.good() and it shows that the file is found. I've tried the other couple of wav files and it throws the same exception. I have no idea why it's doing this but it will crash the whole program when I try it. By the way thanks for the help you are giving :)

Comment: I got one last idea: Put after the line `sf::SoundBuffer chop;` a line with `try {`. And after the line `chopNoise.setBuffer(chop);` put a line `} catch (std::exception& e) { std::cout << "Problem = " << e.what() << std::endl; }`. What does it print?

Comment: Alright I'll give that one a try tonight and let you know if it works.

Comment: Looks like a lot of gibberish. After "failed to open sound file" then a bunch of "Microsoft.Windows.SystemCompatible" then more gibberish then "C:\windows\system32\sxsoa.dll" and a bunch of other windows paths

Comment: I ran it again and it gave me a "terator list corrupted!" Followed by a bunch of stuff. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Well ^^ it *is* more information about the problem. I duckduckgoed your messages and it turns out, it might have something to do with the format. Try a mp3 or ogg file. Does that work? Might be a codec problem, but really I am out of ideas sorry.

Comment: @nada `.mp3` files aren't supported by SFML due to licensing issues. Only **WAV, OGG/Vorbis and FLAC** are currently supported.

Comment: @Kyle.T Reading the comments, I'd suggest to try with another audio file. Check that `chop.wav` is ok, can you open it with your system player?

Comment: Yes i can open it with media players and it works fine. I tried opening a different wav file because the main project uses 3 of them but none of them work. Think it might be because they are old or something? The book im using is for VS2015 maybe the format for them has changed a little since then?

Comment: @asleether i tried another file thats new and it did the same thing. Same error and game crash.

Comment: Can you provide the full error in your post. Errors aren't just gibberish, but they contain vital information and to an experienced person, will usually directly tell what the issue is.

Comment: I put up what the console displayed